# Clicking button on second activity got error performing 'single click' or 'scroll to' on view

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, android-espresso

Clicking a button in Espresso test got problem. Let's say I have two activities "Activity1" and "Activity2". Click a dialog OK button in Activity1 starts Activity2 where the button in Activity2 can't be clicked.

```
// The current activity in testing
// .....
onView(withText(R.string.dialog_btn_ok)).perform(click()); // go to the second activity

// The button on the second activity
onView(withId(R.id.btnMP)).check(matches(isDisplayed())); // this is ok
onView(withId(R.id.btnMP)).perform(click()); // got error here
```

> android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing
>   'single click' on view 'with id: ..........
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed
>   because the target view does not match one or more of the following
>   constraints: at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to
>   the user. Target view: "Button{id=2131296390, res-name=btnMP,
>   visibility=VISIBLE, width=652, height=160, has-focus=false,
>   has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true,
>   is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true,
>   is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false,
>   root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=20.0,
>   y=-16.0, text=Modify Parameter, input-type=0, ime-target=false,
>   has-links=false}"

When I change this with `perform(scrollTo())`, a different error is shown.

```
// The button on the second activity
onView(withId(R.id.btnMP)).check(matches(isDisplayed())); // this is ok
onView(withId(R.id.btnMP)).perform(scrollTo(), click()); // got error here
```

> android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing
>   'scroll to' on view 'with id ....
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the
>   target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
>   (view has effective visibility=VISIBLE and is descendant of a: (is
>   assignable from class: class android.widget.ScrollView or is
>   assignable from class: class android.widget.HorizontalScrollView))
>   Target view: "Button{id=2131296390, res-name=btnMP,
>   visibility=VISIBLE, width=652, height=160, has-focus=false,
>   has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true,
>   is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true,
>   is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false,
>   root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=20.0,
>   y=-16.0, text=Modify Parameter, input-type=0, ime-target=false,
>   has-links=false}" at

Comment: As the error message says, probably it doesn't show at least the 90% of the entire view's area. Try, `isCompletelyDisplayed()` instead of `isDisplayed()`, or even better, try to use `isDisplayingAtLeast()` passing 90 as percentage.

Comment: Yes, `isCompletelyDisplayed()` is failed with the error `DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'at least 100 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.' doesn't match the selected view.` What can I do for that?

Comment: Have you disabled the animations on testing device? Be sure to disable them: go to settings > developer options and disable "Window animation scale", "Transition animation scale" and "Animator duration scale"

Comment: In fact, `scrollTo()` should solve the problem, right?

Comment: Have you solved the problem disabling animations? About `scollTo()` I'm not sure the problem is the same.

Comment: I disabled all animation scale settings, but still getting the error `android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'at least 100 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.' doesn't match the selected view.`

Comment: This means that your view is not entirely visible. This is way it can't be clicked

Comment: But I see the button is in screen.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to create your custom [GeneralClickAction](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/action/GeneralClickAction.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F) with view visibility that you want to click less then Espresso's GeneralClickAction requires. Currently the minimum visibility value is 90% - see code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/action/GeneralClickAction.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F) line 60. Set it to be 80% or less. Just copy the whole class rename it and change the value provided to this method to 80 `isDisplayingAtLeast(80)`. Then create your click action that uses your custom GeneralClickAction:

```
  public static ViewAction customClick() {
      return actionWithAssertions(
          new CustomGeneralClickAction(Tap.SINGLE, GeneralLocation.VISIBLE_CENTER, Press.FINGER));
  }
```

But I'd rather fix the layout of the activity if possible to avoid creation of workaround for button visibility.

Comment: For those who does not have Guava library, you can use `import android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.base.Optional;` when the compiler complains

Comment: You can use also from espresso core import android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.base.Optional;

Answer (score 1):

Seems your view with id `R.id.btnMP` is not visible at the screen so you are receiving the first error. You are trying to resolve this by `scrollTo()` but your view in not inside ScrollView. So how your activity is organized? If you are using `RecyclerView` (for example) you should use special version of scrollTo - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions.html and so on. So first take a look where your view is hosted and then it will be clear how to scroll to it.

Comment: I only use LinearLayout and FrameLayout. Hierarchy is such `LinearLayout > FrameLayout > LinearLayout > LinearLayout > Button`. During testing, I see the button in screen and then the test stopped and failed.