# Click on FloatingActionButton in espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

Try to click on FloatingActionButton in espresso tests.

```
onView(withId(R.id.actionButton)).perform(customClick())
```

My method customClick:

```
fun customClick(): ViewAction {
    return actionWithAssertions(
            CustomGeneralClickAction(Tap.SINGLE, GeneralLocation.VISIBLE_CENTER, Press.FINGER))
}
```

Also create class CustomGeneralClickAction with some changes:

```
Matcher<View> standardConstraint = isDisplayingAtLeast(60);
```

This example i take it from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36164842/6387618).
But have next error:

> android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click' on view 'with id: com.fentury.android:id/actionButton'.
>
> Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'click (after 3 attempts)' on view 'unknown'.

And also here:

> at com.fentury.android.acceptanceTests.utils.CustomGeneralClickAction.perform(CustomGeneralClickAction.java:79)

```
status = tapper.sendTap(uiController, coordinates, precision);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `onView(withId(R.id.floating_action_button)).perform(click());`

Comment: Doesn t work. So I tried to solve the problem of your way in my answer.

Comment: My answer was about the case when view is not fully visible.

Comment: sorry, i find this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575067/click-floating-action-button-espresso may be I something did not understand, sorry. But the problem remains