# Espresso: Click action on button in ListView footer

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

ListView has footer like this (footer.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        style="@style/MyApp.Form.Component.Button"
        android:text="@string/action_cancel"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
        style="@style/MyApp.Form.Component.Button"
        android:text="@string/action_next"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When recording the script (via the 'Record Espresso Test' in Android Studio) I received the following code to click the button 'Next':

```
private void clickNext() {
    ViewInteraction appCompatButton2 = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.btn_confirm), withText("Next"),
                    withParent(childAtPosition(
                            withId(R.id.lv_products), 5))));
    appCompatButton2.perform(click());
}
```

It works good but... when the test is runned on device with low resolution I get error:

> android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing
>   'single click' on view '(with id:
>   com.comarch.msc.emulator:id/btn_confirm and with text: is "Next" and
>   has parent matching:  Child at position 5 in parent with id:
>   com.comarch.msc.emulator:id/lv_products)'. (...) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the
>   target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
>   at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.

How to customize the test for lower resolutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click on not fully visible imageButton with Espresso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834579/click-on-not-fully-visible-imagebutton-with-espresso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is whole footer isn't shown on the screen (just part if is shown). You can try to do [swipeUp](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#swipeUp()) action before clicking on the button. Or, if swipe isn't helping, just check why you are not seeing it on smaller screens.